# Send A list of defined object with Protocol buffer

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Hi guys I want to know if there is a way to send a list of object throw protocol buffer ? as I read this page it say that you can but you need to write code yourself. I actually could not understand what is needed for that so, if someone can help it will be good. 
Here is the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you defined a object named Foo,

```
message Foo {
    ...
}
```

If you want to send a list of Foo, you can make it a repeated field in another message,

```
message FooList {
    repeated Foo foos = 1;
}
```

You can check the [language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) ,

```
You specify that message fields are one of the following:

required: a well-formed message must have exactly one of this field.
optional: a well-formed message can have zero or one of this field (but not more than one).
repeated: this field can be repeated any number of times (including zero) in a well-formed message. The order of the repeated values will be preserved.
```

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer I figured it out after I posted the question , lol :D